# Install4j behavior difference for GUI and CLI mode

Tags: installation, uninstallation, install4j, reboot

We have developed installer for CentOS platform there is one behavior that we have observed.
If we run uninstaller in GUI mode it starts execution of actions one by one during that if reboot happens, after reboot all files are present there and we can execute uninstaller again.
Same case for CLI
If we run uninstaller in CLI mode it starts it starts execution of actions one by one but if during that reboot happens, after reboot all files created by install4j are removed so we cannot execute uninstaller again as even uninstall script created by installer gets deleted.

Please comment on this behavior as ideal behavior for us would be the one seen in GUI mode.

Comment: You mean if the reboot happens while the uninstaller is running? The behavior of that is undefined and non-recoverable. The difference between GUI and command line mode is probably related to the way that processed are shut down.

Comment: So any thing that can be done to achieve same behavior for both from linux/install4j point of view at least?

Comment: No, I don't see what could be done. A reboot in the middle of the uninstallation that forcibly terminates the uninstaller will have unpredictable consequences.

Comment: Hii Ingo a similar behavior is observed when uninstaller is running and if we hit ctrl+c it stops the uninstaller but surprisingly all install4j specific files are deleted and this is happening even if ctrl+c is done before uninstall files action.I checked if cancelled event is called but that isn't a case as well.

Comment: The uninstaller does not roll back to the previous state if canceled. If you cancel with CTRL-C, the actions may still run in the background for some time.

Comment: Currently when I hit ctrl+c while uninstallation is in progress and ctrl+c is pressed just at start of uninstallation way before Uninstall Files action strangely it deletes install4j created files the Uninstaller file Uninstall.sh Itself  And I want to prevent such behavior please guide me through this scenario.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot reproduce that behavior, so I would not know what to suggest. The uninstaller will delete itself at some point, so it's not entirely unexpected.